# using a variable in a redirect function

Tags: php, mysql

With PHP, I have a script that searches for an email from a mysql_db then takes a username from the same row as the email in the db.  What I want it to do is redirect using the username as a subdomain in the url

I've tried:

```
 $username = //username taken from the db
 $url = 'http://".$username."domain.com';
 header('location: $url');
```

This just appends the variable "$url" to the end of my test url.

and I've tried:

```
header('http://".$username."domain.com');
```

This outputs in the adress bar:

```
http://%22.%24account_name.%22.domain.com
```

How can use this search result variable and redirect to the subdomain I am looking for?

Comment: You are using single quotes, so `$url` is treated literally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors galore.

**Version 1 corrected** (variables in single quotes are treated as literal strings):

```
$username = //username taken from the db
$url = 'http://".$username."domain.com';
header('location: ' . $url);
```

**Version 2 corrected** (Your syntax and quote usage are both wrong):

```
header("Location: http://".$username."domain.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use double quotes

```
$url = "http://{$username}.domain.com";
header("Location: {$url}");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 $username = //username taken from the db
 $url = "http://$username.domain.com";
 header("Location: $url");
```